# Unity In-game pause menu not working?

Tags: unity, c#

I have followed a tutorial to implement a pause screen for my platformer game. I followed it thoroughly but could not get it working. When I press the escape button which I assigned under the project manager under the name "Pause", it just doesn't do anything. I checked with the Scene view as well, nothing appears. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The script is a component of the Main Camera, not the Canvas or the PauseUI itself.

```
 public GameObject PauseUI;

 private bool paused = false;

void Start()
{
    PauseUI.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
   if(Input.GetButtonDown("Pause"))
   {
       paused = !paused;
   }

   if(paused)
   {
       PauseUI.SetActive(true);
       Time.timeScale = 0;
   }

   if(!paused)
   {
       PauseUI.SetActive(false);
       Time.timeScale = 1;
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah I thought it was the same script. Can you show as well how you set up the "Pause" on the InputManager?

Comment: @Zibelas added another picture showing the input manager.

Comment: I just added a Debug.Log line under the GetButtonDown function and it seems like it doesn't get the key at all because the line did not print in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Pause is not working is, that as input for Pause in the input manager you set Joystick Axis as Type but you want "Key or Mouse Button".